# Joomla Admin Login Error: User name and password do not match

Tags: authentication, joomla1.5

I just moved my joomla 1.5.27 website to a new hosting service - now every time I try to log in to the admin area I keep getting a **Username and Password Do Not Match** error. I know with 100% certainty that the multiple users and log in's I've tried are correct (I've been copying them straight from the jos_user table in my database). After looking at every article that could possibly help and the suggestions they had so far I have unsuccessfully tried...

- Entering PHPmyAdmin and changing the user password / adding a new user / using the users who are in the jos_user table
- Checking the authentication plugin table was set to 1 for published
- Changing the config file settings

  - Adding a $root_user
  - Changing the session from database to none
  - Deleting the sessions stored in the database
- I also went through the list in this article http://www.itoctopus.com/10-reasons-why-youre-not-able-to-login-to-your-joomla-website

I looked at the debug info and it looks like I'm having some sort of issue with the sessions but so far I haven't been able to find a fix to the problem. below I've listed my Debug info and Cofig File Set up. If anyone could provide any help as to why this might be happening it would be greatly appreciated.

**Debug Info: 8 Queries Logged**

```
DELETE 
  FROM jos_session 
  WHERE ( TIME < '1420218343' )
SELECT * 
  FROM jos_session 
  WHERE session_id = '8dc654d7f21c7eafa5158149304e59b5'
UPDATE `jos_session` 
  SET `time`='1420225543',`userid`='0',`usertype`='',`username`='',`gid`='0',`guest`='1',`client_id`='1',`data`='__default|a:6:{s:15:\"session.counter\";i:15;s:19:\"session.timer.start\";i:1420224014;s:18:\"session.timer.last\";i:1420224695;s:17:\"session.timer.now\";i:1420224736;s:22:\"session.client.browser\";s:108:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36\";s:13:\"session.token\";s:32:\"aec906d1afac1252cd02f686703162f7\";}' 
  WHERE session_id='8dc654d7f21c7eafa5158149304e59b5'
SELECT * 
  FROM jos_components 
  WHERE parent = 0
SELECT folder AS TYPE, element AS name, params 
  FROM jos_plugins 
  WHERE published >= 1 
  AND access <= 0 
  ORDER BY ordering
SELECT `id`, `password`, `gid` 
  FROM `jos_users` 
  WHERE username='xxxxx'
SELECT id, title, module, POSITION, content, showtitle, control, params 
  FROM jos_modules AS m 
  LEFT JOIN jos_modules_menu AS mm 
  ON mm.moduleid = m.id 
  WHERE m.published = 1 
  AND m.access <= 0 
  AND m.client_id = 1 
  ORDER BY POSITION, ordering
SELECT template 
  FROM jos_templates_menu 
  WHERE client_id = 1 
  AND menuid = 0
```

**Config File:**

```
var $offline = '0';
var $editor = 'jce';
var $list_limit = '20';
var $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org';
var $debug = '0';
var $debug_lang = '0';
var $sef = '1';
var $sef_rewrite = '0';
var $sef_suffix = '1';
var $feed_limit = '10';
var $feed_email = 'author';
var $secret = 'xxxxxxxx';
var $gzip = '0';
var $error_reporting = '-1';
var $xmlrpc_server = '0';
var $log_path = '/logs';
var $tmp_path = '/tmp';
var $live_site = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var $force_ssl = '0';
var $offset = '-5';
var $caching = '0';
var $cachetime = '60';
var $cache_handler = 'file';
var $memcache_settings = array();
var $ftp_enable = '0';
var $ftp_host = '127.0.0.1';
var $ftp_port = '21';
var $ftp_user = '';
var $ftp_pass = '';
var $ftp_root = '';
var $dbtype = 'mysqli';
var $host = 'localhost';
var $user = 'xxxxxxxx';
var $db = 'xxxxxxxxx';
var $dbprefix = 'jos_';
var $mailer = 'smtp';
var $mailfrom = 'info@xxxx.com';
var $fromname = 'xxxxxxx';
var $sendmail = '/bin/false';
var $smtpauth = '0';
var $smtpsecure = 'none';
var $smtpport = '25';
var $smtpuser = '';
var $smtppass = '';
var $smtphost = '30.30.4.222';
var $MetaAuthor = '1';
var $MetaTitle = '1';
var $lifetime = '120';
var $session_handler = 'none';
var $password = 'xxxxxxxx';
var $sitename = 'xxxxx';
var $MetaDesc = 'xxxxx';
var $MetaKeys = 'xxxxx, xxxxx';
var $offline_message = 'This site is down for maintenance. Please check back again soon.';
```

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passwords saved in the database are hashed, you can't copy the hashed value and paste it into the login as the password, it's a one-way encryption.  If you are trying to reset the password via phpmyadmin:

1. Edit the row for your user in jos_users
2. Type your new password such as "password" replacing the current hashed password
3. Select MD5 in the drop down before saving the row.
4. Click Save.

This will create a new one way hash for the new password.

1. Go to the Joomla login screen and type your new password (not the hash).

You should be in as long as the user has admin access such as Super User.  After you are successfully signed in, update your password once more via user manager as MD5 isn't overly secure.  This will hash the MD5 + salt.